# Disk space and (logical) partitions in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage, disk-management

I often run out of space at my AWS instance - Each time I solve it (for a while) by increasing the number of GB of the AWS EBS VOL with 10 GB each time (currently at 50GB).

I just realized when I run the built-in disk/space tool in Ubuntu, that it list the following:

1. Home folder: Ubuntu/home ==> This only have 1GB of free disk space
2. "Ip_of_the_server" ("/") ==> this currently have 22 GB of free disk space

Everytime I change the actual size in GB of the AWS VOL - it seems like 90% of the space goes to # 2 and not the logical Home-drive?

I'm not a expert in Ubuntu - so I might interpret something wrong here...? Point being - How do I manually increase the size of the logical drive number 1 (because it is the one which always runs out of disk-space)?